# How to Implement Domain Name Checker and Whois Domain in my website

Tags: dns, whois

I am about to start a Web Hosting website. So i want **Domain Name Checker** (Domain availability) and **Whois Domain** (Information regarding a particular Domain) in my web site.

How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Speak to your domain provider what kind of API they offer to automatically run whois and isfree transactions.  Some may provide you protocols like EPP, RRI or HTTPS-posts which is trivial to implement (in sense of domain availability checks).

I'm not aware of any free out-of-the-box tools so you'll definitely need to script it yourself.